# Ajax Form Submit & Refresh Page Out of DIV

Tags: php, ajax, forms, submit, page-refresh

I'm using ajax form submit script like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#login").submit(function(event) {  

        /* stop form from submitting normally */  
        event.preventDefault();   

        $.post( 'login.php', $("#login").serialize(),  
          function( data ) {  
              $("#loginoutput").append(data);  
          }  
        );  
      });  
  });  
</script>
```

.
.
.

When form submitted all content shown in loginoutput DIV. Errors, controls and success messages etc.
But I want to redirect home page after submit with success but redirection done in DIV section. I want to refresh whole page not in DIV section. But all redirections doing in DIV like output messages.

How can I refresh whole page after form submit?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh the screen after an successful ajax post. Then just refresh the screen in the success function of the ajax call like this:

```
$.post( 'login.php', 
    $("#login").serialize(),
    function(data) { // will trigger after successful request (HTTP 200)
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you document.location.reload(true); is what I need

Comment: How can I add 3 seconds wait for message outputs coming from login.php before refresh?

Comment: You can add an sleep of 3 seconds like this: `setTimeout(function() { //here the refresh line }, 3000);`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this small solution:

```
var form = document.getElementById("login");
$.post('login.php', form.serialize(),
       function(data) {
          var response = data;
          if(response.length > 0){
            document.location.reload(true);
          } else {
            console.log('error');
          }  
       }
});
```

Comment: What is different with my answer? The only thing you do more is assigning a variable (why not use `response` instead of `data`?), then you look if the server did an response with text, do you know if his called script send something back (I thought not)? Because if his script generates no source, then your console will log `error`, even when it's an success.

Comment: Sven - you see «Also» == «Or»? My answer is just a variant.)))